# What language is generated by each of the BNF grammars below

Tags: bnf

What language is generated by each of the BNF grammars below (assuming s is the start symbol):

```
<s> -> <x> | <y>
<x> -> 0 <x> 1 | <x1>
<x1> -> 0 <x1> | 0
<y> -> 0 <y> 1 1 | <y1>
<y1> -> <y1> 1 | 1
```

i understand what it does: 0^n 1^n

but i previously asked for help online (elsewhere) and someone gave me an answer:

```
For <x>: 0^n 1^m where n > m and m >= 0
For <y>: 0^n 1^m where m > 2n and m >=0
```

I can't quite follow it, where do the inequalities come from?

Why is n greater than m? Why is m greater than 2n?

I'm guessing the 2n is from the two 1s from y, but how does one figure out if n is greater or less than m? and vice versa? I'm completely oblivious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take **x** for example.

```
<x1> -> 0 <x1> | 0       <x1>: 0^n, n > 0

<x> -> 0 <x> 1 | <x1>
```

This means that **x** will be of the form:

```
<x>: 0^m 0^n 1^m, n >= 1, m >= 0
```

since if there will always be a **x1** in the middle of **0^m 1^m**. If we simplify we will have

```
<x>: 0^(m + n) 1^m, n >= 1, m >= 0
```

**m + n > m** since n is strictly positive.

Comment: Excellent, thank you so much. You make so much more sense :) For <y>, would it then be: 0^m 1^n (1 1)^m, n >=1, m>=0  Or did I miss something? or: <y>: 0^m 1^(n+2m) n>=1, m >=0

Comment: Yes, you're right, and (n + 2m) > 2m. Taking the n and m from your original question it would be: <y>: 0^m 1^(n+2m) <-> 0^n 1^m, and that means m > 2n.